# Rails 3 Devise Registrations Controller Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to customize my devise registration fields and tried to add a field. I followed the tutorial at http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/ to figure out how to customize the fields. I added the fields and followed the steps. When I run the server I am able to input in the new field but when I click register I get this error.

```
undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x261a358>
```

I know in other Devise custom tutorials they say to create a file for the registration controller. Do I need to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing the root(_path/_url) defined in your routes.rb as Devise, but nearly all Rails apps, recommends and require.

For example (add to the top):

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

Or in Ruby 1.8.7

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Comment: Yes, my reply does contain the routes.rb bit

Comment: that didn't work. my routes looks like this now, 

"Login::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'home#index'"

and comes up with an error when I try to run the server

Comment: Perhaps you are not using ruby 1.9, please read my answer better, it does already include code for ruby 1.8.7. Or I need more info about the error you're getting. Cheers

Comment: Works! I needed to check my ruby version and got it to work with 1.8.7 thanks